# How can I debug my Lambda locally, If I don't use API Gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

How can I debug my Lambda locally, If I don't use API Gateway
I have some Lambda function on JS code, now I can test it using simple invoke in AWS console and watch logs in CloudWatch, but after each changes I need to deploy it

I want to know, can I run this code locally and debug it If I don't use API Gateway, just run code from lambda locally

I saw examples with AWS toolkit for VS code, but in this case I saw only testing by API Gateway path

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AWS [Serverless Application Model](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/).  It has a number of features designed to work with Serverless Applications, one of which is local testing and debugging of your Lambda functions.